# How to get current altitude in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, locationmanager

Since I have updated my ios to 7.I dont know how get the current location and altitude with the new method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Can Any one show me some sample code how to use this method to get current location and altitude?

Thanks a LOT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most recent location will be at the end of the `locations` array.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *mostRecentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    bool haveValidAltitude = (mostRecentLocation.verticalAccuracy > 0);
    if(haveValidAltitude)
    {
        NSLog(@"current altitude is: %g meters above sea level", mostRecentLocation.altitude);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"current altitude is unavailable");
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this data help me to determine road vs flight coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

`locations` is an array, last object of which is the newest available location.

Comment: Does `CLLocation` not have an `altitude` property?

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon yes, the question asks for location and altitude.

Comment: Yes, CLLocation has 'altitude' property.